# Querying and ordering data against Azure Cosmos DB results in "One of the specified inputs is invalid" if a name contains a forward slash

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are storing data in an Azure Cosmos container similar to below.  The data is grouped by "ProcessDataId" and there could be >100k documents for each "ProcessDataId".  The container uses "id" as a partitionKey.

The index is specified as

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Document example

```
{
    "id": "49f36245-f594-4836-96a1-25e011a32aaa",
    "ProcessDataId": "37f33e4c-7ab6-4a4e-9102-e085a9663612",
        "chartId": "a5593e69-32fb-4ca0-928d-741c99b5c9f4",
        "chartPresentation": "Diagnose",
        "info": {
            "title": "My chart 1",
            "mainTrend": "FO"
        },
        "data": {
            "segment": "Combined - Combined - Combined",
            "value": "Stuff",
            "segmentationId": "",
            "confidenceValue": 99,
            "foConfidenceValue": 99,
            "scConfidenceValue": 40.6077922077922,
            "soConfidenceValue": 77,
            "gross_outstanding": 24974.50650867,
            "premium": 1186.00109866,
            "class/": "Combined",
            "line/qa": "Combined",
            "riskcodes/qa": "Combined"
        }
    }
```

Querying the database using the following.  Please note the query is dynamically created.

```
SELECT c.data 
FROM c
WHERE c.ProcessDataId = "37f33e4c-7ab6-4a4e-9102-e085a9663612"  
AND (
    c["data"]["class/"] = "Combined" 
    AND 
    c["data"]["line/qa"] = "Combined" 
    AND 
    c["data"]["riskcodes/qa"] = "Combined"
    )
ORDER BY c["data"]["confidenceValue"] desc
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 6
```

This results in an error "{"Errors":["One of the specified inputs is invalid"]}".

If I remove the order by statement the query will run, but this will result in data being brought back in the incorrect order because we are limiting to returning 6 documents at a time.  The query is modified such that the OFFSET value is changed as users move through the data, e.g. on page 5 it will be OFFSET 24, so ordering is important to the data.

The document above is regarded as valid JSON so would expect this query to work.

Any suggestions that don't involve modifying the data would be greatly appreciated.

The forward slash appears to be the problem with the order by clause.  With a modified dataset replacing forward slash with an underscore the query will run happily (obviously replacing / with _).

Comment: First step: get rid of `/` in your property names (since `/` has a specific meaning when specifying paths). Also: why are you using `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`? Neither side of your call to `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` has an array of data. Ok, you've *created* an array with things like `["Combined"]` but that's a single element. And your `class/`, `line/qa`, and `risk codes/qa` properties are all strings. It doesn't really make sense to use `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` here, especially since you're checking for a single string value to be in a property.

Comment: Thanks David.  I was trying to demonstrate the problem, in reality there would be an array of strings.  But even changing to an equality comparison it still doesn't work.  The query DOES work when order by is removed.  The forward slash was not a conscious decision, the property structure is determined by user input and we hadnt validated against this.
If forward slashes arent allowed then why does Cosmos allow them to be inserted as data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have resolved this, a fix has been applied to our Cosmos account and I can confirm this is working.  The fix will be eventually be rolled out to all Cosmos accounts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this `array_contains(["Combined"],c["data"]["class/"])` , use `array_contains(["Combined"], c.data["class/"])` in the code.

**Try with below query:**

```
SELECT c.data 
FROM c
WHERE c.ProcessDataId = "37f33e4c-7ab6-4a4e-9102-e085a9663612"  
AND (
    array_contains(["Combined"], c.data["class/"]) 
    AND 
    array_contains(["Combined"], c.data["line/qa"]) 
    AND array_contains(["Combined"], c.data["riskcodes/qa"])
    )
ORDER BY c.data["confidenceValue"] DESC
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 6
```

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "data": {
            "segment": "Combined - Combined - Combined",
            "value": "Stuff",
            "segmentationId": "",
            "confidenceValue": 99,
            "foConfidenceValue": 99,
            "scConfidenceValue": 40.6077922077922,
            "soConfidenceValue": 77,
            "gross_outstanding": 24974.50650867,
            "premium": 1186.00109866,
            "class/": "Combined",
            "line/qa": "Combined",
            "riskcodes/qa": "Combined"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: No that doesnt work, c.data is the same as c["data"]

Comment: I tried the same with **c.data** and **c["data"]**. **`c["data"]`** didn't work [error screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/mvQpmE9.png). **`c.data`** worked without error [screenshot2](https://i.imgur.com/HYbKcgP.png).

Comment: Ah ok, first time I ran your suggestion, it failed, I tried again and it succeeded, but then ran it again and it failed.  It doesnt execute successfully all the time.

Comment: This solution doesn't really help: 1) it doesn't address the forward-slashes in property names, and 2) there's no justification for `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`

Comment: 1) OP wanted a solution without modifying the data. That is the reason I didn't address the forward slashes in property name. 2) He has provided only the sample document. So, I thought original data may have array for those properties.